# JSON data retrieval using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hello guys i'm working with user login and when an user submits the login credentials an API is being called using ajax and if the login credentails are correct/ wrong i'm getting the response and after stringifying the data is displayed in the following format in console.

If true
**{"$P_SUCCESS":true}**

If false
**{"$P_SUCCESS":false}**

Now i want to read the value true from the above string and want to redirect an user to a new page based on the condition.

I tried different options but all in vain.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: show the code you tried.

Comment: var redirect = JSON.parse('{"$P_SUCCESS":true}');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the property of the object by specifing the name between `[]` (ex: `object['name']`).

```js
var redirect = JSON.parse('{"$P_SUCCESS":true}')
var success = redirect['$P_SUCCESS']; // get value of $P_SUCCESS
alert(success);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var data = {"$P_SUCCESS":true};
var result = data['$P_SUCCESS'];
if(result)
{
    //redirect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = eval(...the response...); // or whatever json decoding function
if(r.$P_SUCCESS) document.location = 'http://...';
else document.location = 'http://...';
```

Comment: `eval`? so it would parse any JavaScript as long as it comes as a result? a little more security please

Comment: No i would use the function provided by the framework I use... and since i dont know what he is using... (see the comments)

Comment: Only if vanilla JS had something to do that... :P

Comment: vanilla JS is not the same from IE6 to Chrome19... That's why we use js libraries... no?

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
 is the thing you are looking for, it will parse you the data in the JSON object from where you can read the data easily and redirect the user accordingly.